# Default paddings for custom layout in Material Dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog, material-design

I'm using appcompat-v7 AlertDialog and Google Material Design lib:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
```

I'v created `DialogFragment` that creates my dialog using custom layout:

```
// import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    final ViewGroup v = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(dialogBuilder.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.d_password, null);

    final AlertDialog dialog = dialogBuilder.setTitle("Pass")
        .setView(v)
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
        .create();

    return dialog;
}
```

My `d_password.xml` layout looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_pass"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Pass"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that there is no margin around layout - it almost contact with title and right/left dialog margin.

To make it look just like standard material dialog (with text instead of custom layout) I had to modify layout to:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/abc_dialog_padding_material"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/abc_dialog_padding_material"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/abc_dialog_padding_top_material">
...
```

The question is: how can I make my custom layout have default Material Design dialog margins, without repeating it each time in layout?

Answer (score 1):

You can place common elements in a style and apply that style to the views you want. See [styles and themes documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

You have already identified which properties are needed for your views. These are the properties you will want to place in your custom theme.

In styles.xml

```
<style name="YourTheme.MaterialMargins" parent="ParentTheme">
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/abc_dialog_padding_material</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/abc_dialog_padding_material</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/abc_dialog_padding_top_material</item>
</style>
```

You can ofcourse change the name `YourTheme` and `MaterialMargins`.

Then in your layout xml file you can add this style to each view you want to apply it to.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    style="@style/YourTheme.MaterialMargins">
```

If you want you can also include the `layout_width` and `layout_height` if that is the same across your views.

Comment: Yea, i know it. Maybe I wasn't specific - the question is is it required with material dialogs or is the way to AppCompat lib handle it automatically?